# Laravel 5.0 Permission on ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, laravel, azure, ubuntu

Whenever i pull from git on my production server, which is azure vps, i have to give permission to my proejct directory, so that apache user can access it. Otherwise it says, permission denied exception.
so i have to run following line in terminal every time whenever i pull new code,

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data projectDirectory
```

And the worst thing is whenever Laravel creates new files for log, same issue happens, which gives me following exception:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The
>   stream or file " /storage/logs/laravel-2016-03-17.log

Can anyone tell me how i can get rid of this critical issue. Thanks

> P.S. I know this is has nothing to do with laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, atlast i found a solution. What i really wanted was, whenever new file is created it should inherit all permissions from parent directory.

sudo chmod g+s /projectDirectory

Answer (score 1):

You should execute this command in Ubuntu after installation:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

This commands will set correct permissions on storage folder and everything inside it. Without this Laravel will not work.

Comment: This is not correct. You should not set all permissions for everyone, it is not safe. The answer of this question explains why and what you should do instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel