# Folder Permission on ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Laravel 5 and whenever i pull from git on my production server, which is azure vps, i have to give permission to my proejct directory, so that apache user can access it. Otherwise it says, permission denied exception. so i have to run following line in terminal every time whenever i pull new code,

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data projectDirectory
```

So after above command everything works fine. 
But the worst thing is whenever Laravel creates new files for log, same issue happens, which gives me following exception:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The
>   stream or file " /storage/logs/laravel-2016-03-17.log

Can anyone tell me how i can get rid of this critical issue. Thanks

Comment: I've already gave you an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052051/laravel-5-0-permission-on-ubuntu

Comment: I posted that question but no one answered it there, @AlexeyMezenin your solution is not working, it have already tried it.

Comment: ^ That's no excuse to post another question.

Comment: can you please tell what is should do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Check with it will work. you have give permission to this folder to create temporary files

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /storage/
```

Comment: Only do this in a local environment. You are basically opening up your configuration files to the outside world.

Comment: @eggmatters is right

Comment: Each and every tutorial says about this solution. And you're not 'opening up your configuration files to the outside world' here. There are no any config files in this folder. Also, you usually use at least VDS for real Laravel project and adding user for this folder is a kind of paranoid solution.

Comment: Was this post edited? Because, I coulda swore you urged the OP to grant 755 on the entire project, not just a specific folder. And call it a paranoid solution but, log files could very well likely contain volatile data. If a tutorial urges you to make your application less secure, than at least do so knowing the risks.

Comment: chmod g+s /projectDirectory

Answer (score 0):

Try adding www-data to your project group:

`useradd -G <your-project-group> www-data`

If larval writes to the logs directory with 'rwx' perms on the group, you will be fine. If the group by default doesn't have write permission on logs, which may be the case, then you will need to make the logs directory open (which @SRK hinted at) DO NOT, however run `chmod 755` on your entire web app. You will be exposing configuration parameters (database access) to the outside world.

Comment: my current user is already part of www-data group

Comment: Yeah, so I thought. You're kind of relegated to @SRK's solution. I've done this in the past as well - but I don't feel good about it.